# How to print exception while specifying error type?

Tags: python

I'm trying to display a user-friendly error message while also displaying the exception but I can't seem to make it work.

I've tried these but got invalid syntax errors:

```py
#First try:
except Exception as e, ValueError:
        print("\nThe program is unable to calculate the given equation. " +
            "Try Again!")
        print("\nError message " + e)
        continue

#Second try:
except ValueError, Exception as e:
        print("\nThe program is unable to calculate the given equation. " +
            "Try Again!")
        print("\nError message " + e)
        continue
```

It would be great if someone could help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve with `except Exception as e, ValueError`. Do you want to except all exceptions (`Exception`)? Or just `ValueError`s? (FYI, it's possible to do `except ValueError as e`.)

Comment: Thanks for that! Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use traceback:

```
import traceback

#First try:
except ValueError:
        print("\nThe program is unable to calculate the given equation. " +
            "Try Again!")
        print("\nError message " + traceback.format_exc())
        continue

#Second try:
except Exception as e:
        print("\nThe program is unable to calculate the given equation. " +
            "Try Again!")
        print("\nError message " + traceback.format_exc())
        continue
```